# Extruder motor freezing

Tags: creality-ender-3, marlin, bigtreetech

I recently upgraded from a Creality 4.2.7 controller board to a BigTreeTech SKR E3 Turbo and touch screen. When power is applied, the extruder motor turns slightly, then freezes and has a low humming noise with the shaft locked up, the only way to stop it is to unplug it.

The hotend is a Micro Swiss direct drive set up in an Ender 3. So the motor has been used for about a year and worked fine. All of the other motors work fine, but the extruder motor is behaving like this, it hasn't worked at all in this current set up. I can't pinpoint if it's a firmware issue or if something is shorted on the mainboard.

I’ve tried all of the basics, flip-flopped all of the pins around/checked the wiring, all seems correct. I tried a different 42-40 motor and got the same result. All the other motors work fine so I think it might be firmware but I don’t really know. Any help is appreciated!

See [this link](https://imgur.com/a/xomW8Ey) for a video of the issue.

Comment: I'm unfamiliar with this type of extruder, could you please explain why the blue tube goes up and down, is that supposed to do that? Or is it getting into the gear?

Comment: Sorry for not clarifying, its a microswiss direct drive set up in an ender 3. So the motor has been used for about a year and worked fine. I just switched from the reality 4.2.7 board to an SKR E3 Turbo board and touch screen. All of the other motors work fine, but the extruder motor is behaving like this, hasnt worked at all in this current set up. I cant ID if its a firmware issue or if something is shorted on the mainboard

Comment: Unplugging the motor? That's a very bad idea and can destroy the motor and/or driver/board. You should power off the entire printer or use the "disable steppers" command on the menu.

Comment: @R..GitHubSTOPHELPINGICE Good comment, but let's hope the OP unplugs the power cord!